# Where can one buy Manga locally in Australia?

Tags: merchandise, australia

So before if i could i would buy Manga from Madman Entertainment before looking at overseas stores like Right Stuff. today however i got an email from Madman saying;

> You might've heard the news....
>   As of May 1st, Madman will no longer be distributing Manga, 
>   or books in general - at least, for the time being.
>
> But we know you love Manga, so we're giving you one final opportunity to grab a bargain with 60% off all Manga and books* on the Madman web store!
>
> Don't miss out. Sale must end April 30 at 11:59 PM.

I am wondering if there are any places/distributors in Australia which still sell Manga and have an online store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many bookstores, such as [Dymocks](http://www.dymocks.com.au), also sell manga, and have online stores where the manga in stock. You may also want to check [Kinokuniya](http://www.kinokuniya.com.au), since they do imports from Japan as well as stocking locally distributed books. Of course the Japanese imports are typically in Japanese, but there are some rare bilingual releases if you're able to find them.

Additionally, it looks like Simon & Schuster has picked up the rights to distribute Viz Media titles in the wake of Madman's announcement, so most of those should still be available after May. The other companies, though, might be a bit trickier to track down. Looking at the [S&S website](http://www.simonandschuster.com.au), they mainly redirect you to retailers rather than selling directly, but hopefully it won't be long before the manga shows up on their site so you at least know where to get them.